# Passing a variable value to a database dropdown

Tags: asp.net, razor, c#-3.0, asp.net-webpages

I wondered if someone could help me.  I have a value in the variable `var_departmentID` and a database dropdown containing the same values which can be passed to the variable.  I would like to default the dropdown to the value in the variable.  I have tried the below, but it is not working.  No errors, it just does not populate the dropdown.

```csharp
@{var var_dbDepartment = Database.Open("Intranet");
var var_listDepartment = "SELECT Department_ID, Data FROM tbl_Department";
List<SelectListItem> listDepartmentData = new List<SelectListItem>();
bool departmentIsSelected = false;
listDepartmentData.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Please Choose...", Value = "0", Selected = true });
foreach(var var_item in var_dbDepartment.Query(var_listDepartment)) {
    if(var_departmentID == var_item.Department_ID.ToString()) {
        bool isSelected = true;
    }
    else {
        bool isSelected = false;
    }

    listDepartmentData.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = var_item.Data, Value = var_item.Department_ID.ToString(), Selected = false});}}
    @Html.DropDownList("Department", listDepartmentData, new { @class = "field", @id="department", @onchange="myFunction()" })
```

Can anyone see what the problem may be?

Comment: Well first of all you are missing some `}` in your code.. It is not suppose to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite your code as follows:

```
@{
    var var_dbDepartment = Database.Open("Intranet");
    var var_listDepartment = "SELECT Department_ID, Data FROM tbl_Department";
    var data = var_dbDepartment.Query(var_listDepartment);
    var items = data.Select(i => new SelectListItem{
        Value = i.Department_ID.ToString(),
        Text = i.Data,
        Selected = i.Department_ID.ToString() == var_departmentID ? true : false
    });
}

@Html.DropDownList("Department", "Please Choose...",  items)
```

For a more in depth coverage look at [HTML Helpers For Forms In Razor Web Pages](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/184/HTML-Helpers-For-Forms-In-Razor-Web-Pages).